# Can evolution happen in one single individual?

Tags: evolution, immortality

Lets say there is one being (it can as intelligent as a dog or an average human). But lets also give it/him a bit more unorthodox situations.

1. He/it doesn't need to sleep and eat. Nor also his cell decaying (so he would never aging and still always be on top of his condition).
2. He is stranded on a place that there is nothing there except sandy ground and peebles. It is limitlessly vast,  and always basking on a gentle light,  there's no night and day, like it always like early morning ambience. Weather change is also absence.
3. On top of this situations he just not going crazy,  or desperate so he killed himself. He always looking for an activity to amuse himself.

The question is,  could he evolve given a millennia or more time there? Can his brain develop more intelligence as the more time he passes there?

**Edit :** @SRM answers that by word definition of evolving itself i got wrong.  What I really mean is can he changing/developing/mutate over unlimited time?

Comment: Short answer no. He will get cancer far because he "evolves". Though apparently his cells don't decay, so in this case the answer is still no, he'll just exist as he is forever. He won't ever evolve.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By definition, no. Evolution is a process of species changing over time, and it requires changing genetics, not just growing older. An individual alone never has that option.

You could argue that bacteria evolve as individuals -- living bacteria can swap DNA sequences around. But that still requires groups of bacteria, not a single one by itself. Microbiologists may have some examples of lone mutation on that level, but I know of none.

The individual could certainly change over time, but that's not evolving, that's just growing. The individual may have gene sequences that are activated later (think like a caterpillar changing into a butterfly). But that kind of development is not evolutionary.

Mental capacity can grow over time without it being evolutionary. That just means that that individual's brain has genetics from the outset that allow it to continuously grow and expand over time, perhaps on a schedule or perhaps in response to some environmental trigger. There's no need to invoke evolution to explain what basic genetics can do. :-)

Comment: Thank you for your statement by definitions.  I've added edit note

Answer (score 1):

Your being will never change/develop/mutate. His cells do not decay, they are thus entirely static in genetic composition (because if they weren't, they would decay).

Your being is entirely immortal and immutable.